Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions
I try to run anchor test, but it shows error "     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions", here is my code https://github.com/brooke007/sol_404.
my test looks like https://github.com/brooke007/sol_404/blob/main/tests/sol_404.ts, and here is my createmint codehttps://github.com/brooke007/sol_404/blob/main/programs/sol_404/src/instructions/createmint.rs anyone can help me?
by the way, I added
[test]
startup_wait = 5000
shutdown_wait = 2000

[test.validator]
bind_address = "127.0.0.1"
url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
ledger = ".anchor/test-ledger"
rpc_port = 8899

[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"

this, into the anchor.toml.
I tried to use google, and GPT, but got nothing.
